# How to compute drive access to a station based on vehicle origin points?

Tags: routing, buffer, network, clustering, catchment-area

I have a shapefile that contains station locations and another shapefile that is the geocoded origins of those who drove to the station. I would like to make a buffer around the station that shows the area where 90% of the vehicles came from so I can show the general drive access area for each station without the extreme outliers.

Again, from my current files I would like to create a raster or shapefile that shows the general catchment area of each station.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Please provide some more information.  One important detail is whether your shapefile that contains the origins also contains an attribute for the end station.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the distance to all origin points, select the 90% nearest and then do a convex hull calculation to get the catchment area. Exact steps depend upon your software.